# How do I get a button to position on the bottom of a view controller in Xcode 7.2?

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, position, constraints

I used to be able to do this:

```
UIButton *bigBottomBtn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-60, self.view.frame.size.width, 60)];
```

I also used to be able to just drag a button onto a storyboard and add a constraint that would hold it to the bottom of the parent.

[image]

[image]

What is going on with Xcode, Autolayout and Apple for that matter....is my Xcode not working properly? Have I missed a major memo? is Apple just going downhill fast?

Comment: u r doing it in table view. or table view controller ?

Comment: Neither, see updated question...im doing it in a plain ol' basic viewcontroller, programmatically adding the button does not position right on all screens , autolayout does not work the way it used to from storyboard.

Comment: no, you are adding the button to a table view controller . YOu shouldnt be doing that.

Comment: No im not....try again. Its a regular viewcontroller with a tableview, if you dont know the answer or cant explain what Apple has done thats fine, but please dont jump to conclusions:http://imgur.com/ucmzBHa

Comment: Select the button and ctrl drag to the view and select the bottom contraint

Comment: http://imgur.com/WvFZdce    ....?

Comment: selct the button on the left section and ctrl drag to its top view.

Comment: Tried my damnedest to get a screen shot of me control dragging from the button to the view but if you attempt it yourself you will find its nearly impossible...nothing happens man and i dont ever recall control dragging having anything to do with constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Your button-creating code used to work (and still does) **if** `self.view`'s frame was correct at the time you created the button. Note that the view doesn't necessarily come out of the xib or storyboard with the correct frame; the xib/storyboard contains the view at some design size which might not match the current device. This wasn't as much of a problem when all iPhones had 3.5 inch screens, but became a pretty common problem with the advent of the iPhone 5's 4 inch screen.

The view isn't guaranteed to have its correct frame until its superview's `layoutSubviews` returns, so if for example you're creating `bigBottomBtn` in `viewDidLoad`, that's too early. [Many questions on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=viewdidload+frame+incorrect) cover this problem. You either need to set the `autoresizingMask` of the button, or implement `layoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to update the button's frame, or turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` and install constraints. Note too that your view can change size if you support rotation, slide over or split view multitasking, or if your view can be the detail view of a `UISplitViewController`, so it's a bad idea to try to guess the correct frame of the button based on the device's screen size at the moment the button is created.

Note that storyboards now by default use a design size of 600x600, which isn't the size of any device. This is probably because if Apple chose some device's size (say, the iPhone 5's 320x568) as the default, and you happened to use a device of that size as your primary (or only) test device, you could easily forget to think about what your app will look like at other sizes. However, you can explicitly set the design size to some device's size if you want:

[image: simulated metrics]

I usually use “iPhone 3.5-inch” if I don't specifically need something bigger, because it lets me get the most scenes on the screen simultaneously (and produces the smallest screen shots for stackoverflow).

As for “I also used to be able to just drag a button onto a storyboard and add a constraint that would hold it to the bottom of the parent”, I have good news: you still can. Example:

[image: demo of adding a button and constraints]

However, you do need to be careful if you have filled your root view with a table view as appears to be the case in your screen shots. You need to drag the button to the document outline in that case, because if you drop it on the table view, Xcode will assume you want it to be the table view header:

[image: dropping button on table view]

Trying to pin a table view header to the bottom of the screen would be folly.

As for the Editor > Align menu, I have found that the items can be mysteriously inactive, which is frustrating.

Note, though, that only the “Horizontally in Container” and “Vertically in Container” will work (when they work at all) with a single view selected. To use the other items in the menu, you need to have at least two views selected, because the other items align the selected views with each other by setting their frames:

[image: align bottom edges]

If you only have one view selected, Xcode doesn't know what other view you might want to align it to.

Those menu items are perhaps useful in the springs'n'struts model, but they don't add constraints, and under autolayout you probably want constraints to enforce the alignment at run time.

As far as I know, those menu items have never added constraints, but I'm not going to reinstall Xcode 6 to verify that, because there's a convenient popover that will add constraints corresponding to all of those menu items:

[image: constrain bottom edges]

Answer (score 0):

In `xcode` you always need to add buttons according to its visibility. As you said you need to show `button` on top of tableView and it should be aligned to bottom. For that You just need to arrange the order of items. as shown in the image below.Provide the layout for the button.[image]